# return value from control.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { /* ... */ }; I need some explanations

Tags: c#, invoke

What's the difference between #1 and #2:

Code 1 (compiled ok):

```
        byte[] GetSomeBytes()
  {
            return (byte[])this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate 
            { 
                GetBytes(); 
            });
  }

  byte[] GetBytes()
  {
   GetBytesForm gbf = new GetBytesForm();

   if(gbf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
    return gbf.Bytes;
   }
   else
    return null;
  }
```

Code 2 (didn't complied ok)

```
int GetCount()
{
       return (int)this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
       {
           return 3;            
       });
}
```

Code #2 gives me *Since 'System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression*.

How can I fix it? And why (do) complier think code #1 is right?

Comment: Can we have a little more code.  What is the type "this" is pointing to?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To answer your first question, try altering your first sample like this:

```
return (byte[])this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate 
{ 
    return GetBytes(); 
});
```

At this point, you'll have the same compilation error.

`public object Invoke(Delegate method)` returns an object, so you can cast the return value to anything and it will compile.  However, you are passing in a delegate of type `MethodInvoker`, which has a signature `delegate void MethodInvoker()`.  So, within the body of the method that you cast to MethodInvoker, you cannot `return` anything.

Try this instead for the second one:

```
return (int)this.Invoke((Func<int>)delegate
{
    return 3;
});
```

`Func<int>` is a delegate that returns an int, so it will compile.

Answer (score 1):

In Code #1, your delegate does not return a value - it simply executes GetBytes(), but doesn't return anything. The compiler will not complain because it is not expecting a return value (this is a void method).

However, in code #2 you try to return a value from the delegate -- which is compiler complains about, because you cannot return a value (in this case '3') from a void method.

Comment: ohhh, I confuse two returns. I forgot to add return to GetBytes();