# Getting the text in a RichTextBox that's on another thread

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I need to get the text in a RichTextBox while in another thread.  I tried invoking like this:

```
string text = ResultsRTB.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => ResultsRTB.Text));
```

But that obviously doesnt work due to the fact that you can't return anything with MethodInvoker (that I know of).  I also tried variations of the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117957/return-value-from-control-invokemethodinvoker-delegate-i-need) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423446/thread-control-invoke) with no luck.  I feel like theres an easy way to do this but Im just missing one little thing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need a delegate type that returns a string.  Like `Func<string>`:

```
var text = (string)richTextBox1.Invoke(new Func<string>(() => richTextBox1.Text));
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew I was missing something.  Didnt know you could specify a `Func` call in an Invoke.

Comment: super answer. tnx